# Postgresql substring regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have some url records in my database like for example:

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6
```

but I need to take only up to /path5

I tried it this way:

```
select substring(url, '/\w*/\w*/\w*/\w*/?\w*') as url from urls
```

but there was an error when a hyphen (path-path) record appeared

what would be the best way?

Comment: `[\w-]` matches any word char or hyphen. But you may also consider a pattern like `'(?:/[\w-]+){5}'` which is a bit shorter.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!